# Pydantic V2 - field_validator() got an unexpected keyword argument 'pre'

Tags: python, pydantic

I'm migrating from v1 to v2 of Pydantic and I'm attempting to replace all uses of the [deprecated](https://docs.pydantic.dev/dev-v2/migration/#validator-and-root_validator-are-deprecated) `@validator` with `@field_validator`.

However, I was previously using the `pre` [validator argument](https://docs.pydantic.dev/1.10/usage/validators/#pre-and-per-item-validators) and after moving to `@field_validator`, I'm receiving the following error:

```
TypeError: field_validator() got an unexpected keyword argument 'pre'
```

Has the use of pre also been deprecated in V2? It seems it's still referenced in the [V2 validator documentation](https://docs.pydantic.dev/2.0/usage/validators/#pre-and-per-item-validators) though with the top-of-page warning:

> This page still needs to be updated for v2.0.

Hoping somebody else has already worked through this and can suggest the best route forward. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> It seems it's still referenced in the V2 validator documentation [...]

Not really. At least nowhere in the [field validators](https://docs.pydantic.dev/2.0/usage/validators/#field-validators) section. (There is just an outdated mention of it in the "model validators" section as of today.)

However, there is also a link to the detailed API reference for the [`field_validator`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/2.0/api/functional_validators/#pydantic.functional_validators.field_validator) decorator showing exactly what arguments you can pass to it.

The closest thing to the v1 `pre=True` argument would now be the **`mode="before"`** argument.

Say you have the following code in Pydantic v1:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, validator


class Foo(BaseModel):
    x: int

    @validator("x", pre=True)
    def do_stuff(cls, v: object) -> object:
        if v is None:
            return 0
        return v


print(Foo(x=None))  # x=0
```

You would have to rewrite it like this in v2:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, field_validator


class Foo(BaseModel):
    x: int

    @field_validator("x", mode="before")
    def do_stuff(cls, v: object) -> object:
        if v is None:
            return 0
        return v


print(Foo(x=None))  # x=0
```

I expect the maintainers will gradually rewrite and expand the docs to cover more details.